# How do I prevent a duplicate picture from adding to the gallery?

Tags: android, camera, gallery, android-gallery

I use the following code to take a picture:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(path + "/" + fileName)));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now when I use this, it does save the picture where I specify above, but it also saves a second copy to the default image folder and adds it to the gallery.

I would simply delete the second file, but it seems it would be a tad dangerous as onActivityResult's intent parameter is always null after taking said picture, so I would have to attempt deleting the most recently saved picture.

Is there any way I can prevent this behavior or correct it by getting the URI of the dupicate picture?

Comment: What is the default location of the Gallery if I want to delete the second image?

Comment: On my device it is the /sdcard/DCIM/ folder.  The second image was a different filename than what I specified as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've determined that it is pretty much not possible.  I am now using a SurfaceView with my own camera activity.